# Gnome-Tweak-Tool Stopped working in Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell

I was installing an extension for gnome-tweak-tool and and when I added the .zip file that I got off github Gnome-Tweak-Tools told me I needed to restart I clicked Restart Session and all of my Gnome-Tweak configuration disappeared, the themes disappeared and now I can't select any themes, when I do it does not take effect even if I restart. I tried to un-install gnmoe-tweak-tool and the issue still preexisted. I also removed the package that I added before the issue started but no luck any suggestions on what could be causing the problem.[image]

Comment: Hi Francesc :) That might solve this at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/368308/210877